# Filter eye tracking data in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filtering

I have eye tracking data sampled at 2000Hz with 45000 samples of x-y pixel coordinates on a 1920x1080 plane.

The velocity (saccade) of the eye is shown in the plot below and contains high frequency noise. x-axis contains the time and y-axis is the velocity/saccade (I forgot the labels)

[image: saccade]

I want to filter out the noise in such a way that the values between the peaks are 0 and the peaks do not contain noise nor do they lose amplitude.

The latter I could probably do by locating the peaks and simply interpolating between its start position and end position since I just need the peaks and their width. However, this is not really an elegant option.

I was curious if there is a *smart* or *elegant* way of doing this. I tried a butterworth filter but that reduces peak amplitude.

Comment: try a savitzky golay. OR probably an outlier detection might work?

Answer (score 0):

It will be imposible to leave the peak amplitudes unchanged because they are also corrupted by high frequency noise. I think that you have two options to filter out the noise

1. [Using a low pass filter](https://www.mathworks.com/help/dsp/examples/designing-low-pass-fir-filters.html)
2. [Using the `smooth` function](https://www.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/smoothing-data.html)

You would have to play around with both methods to determine which better suites your needs, and leave the saccade velocity amplitudes mostly unchanged.